# Make a div looked same as table responsive

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have this line of codes:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row font-bold mt-4">
  <div class="col-md-1">Seq</div>
  <div class="col-md-3">Penalty Type</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">Penalty</div>
  <div class="col-md-2">Penalty Fee</div>
  <div class="col-md-2">Date</div>
  <div class="col-md-3">Comment</div>
 </div>
 <div class="row my-3">
  <div class="col-md-1">1</div>
  <div class="col-md-3">PIC - (W) Curfew Time violation within 3 hours</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">1</div>
  <div class="col-md-2">500.00</div>
  <div class="col-md-2">06/08/2018</div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
   <p>Curfew Time violation within 3 hours</p>
   <p>Permission : 2018-06-08 22:00</p>
   <p>In Time :2018-06-08 23:53:45</p>
   <p>( 113 minutes over )</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row my-3">
  <div class="col-md-1">2</div>
  <div class="col-md-3">PIC - (W W2) Staying out Without Permission</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">2</div>
  <div class="col-md-2">1000.00</div>
  <div class="col-md-2">06/16/2018</div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
   <p>Curfew Time violation ( 3 hours over )</p>
   <p>Permission : 2018-06-15 22:00</p>
   <p>In Time :2018-06-16 1:11:50</p>
   <p>( 191 minutes over )</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row my-3">
  <div class="col-md-4">
   <h3 class="text-danger">Total</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1">3</div>
  <div class="col-md-2">1500.00</div>
  <div class="col-md-2">-</div>
  <div class="col-md-3">-</div>
 </div>
  
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>  
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Actually this looks like a table, this is its output:

[image]

I wanted to make it responsive same goes on how the table is when in mobile devices, they are `scrollable` on the `x` and `y`, but in my case because it is just a div, `col` will let be 12, so I wanted them to stay on the same position, and only make the div `scrollable` is it possible?

Comment: can you share your CSS too?

Comment: no css sir, cause its just `col`'s

Comment: Which version are you using of bootstrap?

Comment: bootstrap 4 sir

Comment: Why don't you consider to build a table instead of divs if you want something to behave like a table?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `-md` from all your `col` classnames; for example `col-md-2` becomes `col-2`. This will prevent the table from collapsing on mobile devices. See snippet for example.

**However** I agree with the comments above, you should consider building this using a `<table>` instead of `<div>` elements.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row font-bold mt-4">
  <div class="col-1">Seq</div>
  <div class="col-3">Penalty Type</div>
  <div class="col-1">Penalty</div>
  <div class="col-2">Penalty Fee</div>
  <div class="col-2">Date</div>
  <div class="col-3">Comment</div>
 </div>
 <div class="row my-3">
  <div class="col-1">1</div>
  <div class="col-3">PIC - (W) Curfew Time violation within 3 hours</div>
  <div class="col-1">1</div>
  <div class="col-2">500.00</div>
  <div class="col-2">06/08/2018</div>
  <div class="col-3">
   <p>Curfew Time violation within 3 hours</p>
   <p>Permission : 2018-06-08 22:00</p>
   <p>In Time :2018-06-08 23:53:45</p>
   <p>( 113 minutes over )</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row my-3">
  <div class="col-1">2</div>
  <div class="col-3">PIC - (W W2) Staying out Without Permission</div>
  <div class="col-1">2</div>
  <div class="col-2">1000.00</div>
  <div class="col-2">06/16/2018</div>
  <div class="col-3">
   <p>Curfew Time violation ( 3 hours over )</p>
   <p>Permission : 2018-06-15 22:00</p>
   <p>In Time :2018-06-16 1:11:50</p>
   <p>( 191 minutes over )</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row my-3">
  <div class="col-4">
   <h3 class="text-danger">Total</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="col-1">3</div>
  <div class="col-2">1500.00</div>
  <div class="col-2">-</div>
  <div class="col-3">-</div>
 </div>
  
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>  
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```